# how to achieve rated full read speed from an SSD?

Tags: ssd, performance

how to achieve rated full read speed from an SSD?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do better than read this [comprehensive article](http://www.anandtech.com/printarticle.aspx?i=3531). It deals with architecture and the reasons SSD performance degrades over time.

Essentially:

> Based on my explanation **(read the
>   article)** there’s one sure-fire way to
>   make your drive fast again.
>   Formatting/deleting everything on the
>   drive won’t work because those pages
>   on the drive will remain full of data.
>
> If you are doing a clean setup of your
>   machine and want to restore your drive
>   to its native state you’ll have to
>   perform a secure erase. Intel
>   distributed a tool with the first
>   X25-M review kits called HDD ERASE.
>   This tool will take any SSD and free
>   every last page on the drive.
>   Obviously you’ll lose all of your data
>   but your drive will be super fast
>   again!